# "Awaiting Referee Assignment" Does that mean my submission passed the first decision?

Tags: peer-review, journals, paper-submission

I submitted a paper yesterday to a SAGE journal, and it went very quickly from with journal administrator (or something like that) to Awaiting Referee Assignment. There is an editor attached to it as well. My question is whether my paper got the first decision. I know we should not idle our days in front of the screen stalking the submission process, but I sort of need to know due to an administrative issue (it matters if the paper is on its way to being "under review").

Thanks!